# What does "IA64_32" osgi.arch mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, osgi, cpu-architecture

What does the "IA64_32" option mean in the architecture plugin details.  The complete list of options is [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fua_dynamic_filters.htm), but there is no detailed explanation.

> osgi.arch    processor architecture  x86, x86_64, ia64, ia64_32, ppc,
>   PA_RISC, sparc

The problem I am facing is that I have 2 implementations of the same interface, one for 32 bit set with **x86** and another for 64 bit set with **x86_64,ia64**, but for some reason neither start when I install the 32 bit version of the application on a windows 2012 server r2 64 bit.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

ia64 and ia64_32 are for Intel Itanium processors (64 bit and 32 bit respectively I think). Eclipse only uses this for HP-UX support. Recent releases of Eclipse only support ia64.

Windows builds normally use x86 (32 bit) or x86_64 (64 bit).

Comment: Yeah, 32-bit on Itanium is consistent with how IA64_32 is used in the [org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform constants](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FPlatform.html).

Comment: So, since I am only interested in windows machines, I should use only x86 and x86_64 as plugin filters, and further investigate why the implementation does not start.